# node.js authenticate middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've a small issue with a declaration of a function as middleware. I've the feeling that I'm missing something small but am now stuck.

The declaration is in a Routerfile:

```
var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');

module.exports = function(app) {
  var users = require('../controllers/userController');

  app.route('/users')
    .post(users.createUser);

  app.route('/users/me')
    .get(users.getMe, authenticate);

  app.route('/users/me/token')
    .delete(users.logout, authenticate);

  app.route('/users/login')
    .post(users.login);
};
```

This is giving an error like:

```
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'authenticate' must be of type '(req: any, res: any, next: any) => void', but here has type 'any'.
```

The authenticate file looks like:

```
var {User} = require('./../api/models/user');

var authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  var token = req.header('x-auth');
  User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject();
    }

    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(401).send();
  });
};

module.exports = {authenticate};
```

I think I'm close but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

> *Note:* Middleware always comes before the controller function call.

```
app.route('/users/me')
    .get(authenticate, users.getMe);
```

Comment: Why your are exporting authenticate like this `module.exports = {authenticate}`

Comment: You just export it like `module.exports = authenticate`,  and require it like `var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate');`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't solve the problem. The accolades are there for destructuring . The functions worked when the routes where in my server.ts file (startfile) but I tried to refactor it to use a router file and then it broke with the above message.

Comment: Can you share your souce with me so we can solve the problem together.